# Disable jmx in red5

Tags: java, jmx, red5

Red5 takes more time while starting in centOS. I checked the stdout.log. There is JMX timeout error.

```
[ERROR] [main] org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent - {}
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://:9999/red5]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 69.164.154.24; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
```

How to disable JMX in red5..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red5 used JMX for monitoring deployed application from remote. By default port 9999 used for JMX. It will wait for upto 100/200 seconds if program can not able to make connection with port 9999. To disable JMX monitoring you have to set false for "enableRmiAdapter" in red5-common.xml in conf folder of red5 server.

```
    <bean id="jmxAgent" class="org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent" init-method="init">
            <!-- The RMI adapter allows remote connections to the MBeanServer -->
            <property name="enableRmiAdapter" value="false"/>
            ....
```

FYI I am using red5-0.9.1 and JMX port and host configuration in red5.properties file.

For 1.0 and more follow this https://code.google.com/p/red5/wiki/SlowStartup